# ASCII color to HEX Color

Tags: c++, hex, mud

I am a builder on an old-fasioned MUD. I have been tasked with making a web-based room/object/mobile editor. This is no problem for me, and am almost complete. The only problem I have is the colour chart. I'm not sure how to convert the ASCII colours from Lope's ColoUr system to HEX values to use in CSS.

For instance, Red is defined as:

```
#define C_RED       "\e[0;31m"
```

I'm not sure how to change that to red in Hex to use for CSS, and which shade (there are two shades of red in lope's colour system. One dark, one light. Same for most colors).

Does anyone know of a way to convert from one to the other?

Comment: Why not use an associative array as a look-up table?

Comment: Maybe thid can help you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors You can use al look-up table

Comment: The wikipedia article did it! They don't have the "bright" CSS codes for some colours, but I can improvise those. The rest work perfectly, thank you.

Comment: @user1287233 Please add your findings as an answer and close this question then :)

Answer (score 0):

Manually entering each entry would be my first guess, unless there's a pattern you can follow for the console colors.

Comment: There is a pattern, but better-looking results can probably be achieved using a lookup table.

Comment: I'm hoping theres a lookup table. Worse comes to worse, i'll just screencap my mud client with the color examples, and use photoshops eyedrop tool to find the color that way.

Comment: Not a bad idea. If there were a way to quickly click on each one and output the color to a file, that would save a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, there are only 10 'colours' to worry about here:

- Red
- Green
- Blue
- Cyan
- Magenta (Purple)
- Yellow
- Black
- White

Luckily, these are just the primary and secondary colours from an RGB system:

- Red: `0xFF0000`
- Green: `0x00FF00`
- Blue: `0x0000FF`
- Cyan: `0x00FFFF`
- Magenta (Purple): `0xFF00FF`
- Yellow: `0xFFFF00`
- Black: `0x000000`
- White: `0xFFFFFF`

For dark versions, try halving each byte to 7F

Comment: We actually have a bit more. Here's the list from "help colour":

  {r     red      {c     cyan
        {R     red      {C     cyan
        {g     green    {y     yellow
        {G     green    {Y     yellow
        {b     blue     {w     white
        {B     blue     {W     white
        {m     magenta  {x     clear(reset colour)
        {M     pink     {D     grey
        {{     { char   {*     beep

Comment: Half yellow was widely futzed with as it was widely considered ugly.